# EF creating another database instead of applying migrations to a existing one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I can't understand why another database is being created when I run `update-database` command instead of applying pending migrations to the existing database. The scenario appears to happen sporadically. These are the steeps I am used to when applying migrations:

1. Set the package manager project to `MySolution.MyProject`;
2. Run the `update-database` command. It sporadically creates a new database with my context full class name, example: `MySolution.MyProject.MyContext`;
3. On SQL Server Management Studio, I delete the newly created database `MySolution.MyProject.MyContext`;
4. Run the same command `update-database` again. Then, EF finds my database correctly, which name is ***only*** `MyContext` and apply only the pending migrations.

The last step is the desired result at first. I want to understand: why is this another database is being created? Shouldn't EF find out the correct name at the first run? Why is it running correctly when I run on the second time? I must be doing something terribly wrong.

Here is my migrations project, which is `MySolution.MyProject.MyContext`, **app.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLDEV;Initial Catalog=MyContext;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=my_user;Password=my_password;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  ...
</configuration>
```

I gave the database user all privileges on my machine (SQL User > Server Roles).

And this my file **MyContext.cs**:

```
namespace MySolution.MyProject
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public MyContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {
        }

        public MyContext(ObjectContext objectContext, bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
            : base(objectContext, dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
        {
        }

        // ... lots of stuff...

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can understand/debug/find out what is happening is appreciated.

Comment: One thing you can do is use the `-verbose` switch when you update-database. I ALWAYS use it, as it gives you a look at what EF is actually doing.

Comment: Good! If you found your problem, you should post it back here as an answer to help any others who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @DrewJordan, using the `-verbose` showed me clearly what was the problem.

Since I am working with a large solutions (several projects), and each project has its own app.config (most of them with no EF connection), I checked that the verbose displayed:

```
PM> update-database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'MySolution.Business'.
Using NuGet project 'MySolution.MyProject'.
```

Instead of selecting `Default Project` to `MySolution.MyProject` in the package manager console, I had to `Set as StartUp Project`. Then it worked properly, because it was pointing to the correct **app.config** with my EF connection.

I still have no idea why the second run worked fine, but it seems to be related to the fact I eventually clicked on `MySolution.MyProject` and when it become bold, the startup project would be correctly set to the correct app.config file.

Comment: ah yes, that was my hunch... in fact, I find that I have to do both (`Set as Startup Project` in solution explorer AND set the default project from the drop down in the package manager console. Make sure you select this answer as 'accepted' so it doesn't show as 'unanswered' anymore.